# Validating admin site save in Django

Tags: python, django

I have the following two classes defined in models.py

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    parts = models.ManyToManyField(Part)
```

So my model allows for multiple parts, but I want the part names to be unique. For example, only one part with name "engine" should be allowed for a given car. How do I enforce this uniqueness?

Things I have looked into:

```
class save()
```

Overriding the default save() for Car doesn't help because parts isn't updated until save is hit.

```
class save_model()
```

This will not work because it always saves.

So what are my options for enforcing uniqueness of part names?

**UPDATED:**

Although I want only one part with name engine to be associated with a car, I still want the ability to define multiple parts with name engine, of course with different values.

So a car with can have a part (part.name=Engine and part.value=V6) and another car can have  a part (part.name=Engine and part.value=V4, but a car can't have two parts that have part.name == engine.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=32)

class CarPart(models.Model):
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
    part_type = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=true)
    part = models.ForeignKey(Part)

class Car(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

treat part_type as part type id (e.g. type='engine') for engines it will be unique

more about [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey)

Comment: I am getting the following error with your code:            
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ReferenceProperty'

Comment: You're right (edited) :) it's because i thought about google app engine when i wrote it (it's very similar to django)

Comment: Thanks for you help. Your method works, but I want to keep my original class definitions using ManyToManyField. ManyToManyField allows for easier visual book keeping via filter horizontal.